# present collection view image in header

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to design a view that looks somewhat like this

[image]

Here I have an `UIImageView` displaying the selected image in a `collectionView`. The problem with this that when scrolling down the `UIImageView` is positioned in the top of the view.

I'm trying a different approach which is having an `UIImageView` in the header.

here is what my view looks like the blue header is an `UIImageView`.

[image]

Is it possible to change the header picture to the selected picture in the collection view and set the selected picture in `viewDidLoad` to the index of 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this, but I'm not sure if it's the right way to do it.

I created a global variable and set it to 0 `var selectedIndex: Int = 0`

When dequeuing the header cell I set the index to `selectedInex`

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    switch kind {
    case UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter:

        let footer = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: footerIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! footerCell
        footer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        return footer

    case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:

        let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: headerIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! headerCell
        header.imageView.image = images[selectedInex]
        return header

    default:
        fatalError("Unexpected element kind")
    }
}
```

in `didSelectItemAt`

```
selectedInex = indexPath.row
collectionView.reloadData()
```